# Mercurial clone issue

Tags: mercurial, clone

I'm using Mercurial and I've cloned a repo locally and upon `hg push`, I'm getting this:

```
abort: cannot lock static-http repository
```

What does this mean? Why can't it lock the static-http repository? Permission issue on the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because Mercurial doesn't implement push for static-http, you need either the smart protocol, ssh or local access.

See [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for more details.