# Trouble allowing push in Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo I'm having trouble pushing to... I've followed the instructions...

My repo contains a hgrc...

**/repo/.hg/hgrc**

```
[web]
push_ssl = false
```

**hgwebdir.config**

```
[paths]
/ = /path/to/folder/*  

[web]
baseurl = /

push_ssl = false

allow_archive = zip
```

When I try to push I still get `abort: cannot lock static-http repository`

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774733/mercurial-clone-issue)

Comment: Yup, exactl duplicate.  Short answer is: you're nto using hgweb to serve your repo.  You need to do that to enable push (and to have a decently fast clone/pull operation).  Follow the link in @jgritty 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Allowing_push

Looks similar to many other posts, but see if section 7 doesn't help you.

Comment: I used that guide to set this up in the first place.  Are you saying that `hgwebdir` will only allow the repos to be browse able but that `hgweb` is still required for pushing/pulling to a repo?